# JS, PHP Dynamic Content and Google Crawlers

Tags: php, javascript, google-analytics, domdocument

I have a series of about 25 static sites I created that share the same info and was having to change inane bits of copy here and there so i wrote this javascript so all the sites pulled the content from one location. (shortened to one example)

```
var dataLoc = "<?=$resourceLocation?>";
$("#listOne").load(dataLoc+"resources.html #listTypes");
```

When the page loads, it will find the div id listOne then replace it with the contents of the div in the file resources.html and only the contents of the div labeled listTypes there.

My Question: Google is not crawling this dynamic content at all, I am told Google will crawl dynamically imported information so what i'm curious to find out is **what it is that i am currently doing that needs to be improved?**

I assumed js just was skipped by the google spider so i used PHP to access the same HTML file used before and it is working slightly, but it's not working how i need it. This will return the text, but i need the markup as well, the `<li>, <p><img>` tags, and so on. Perhaps i could tweak this? (i am not a developer so I have just tried a few dozen things i read in the PHP online help and this is as close as i got)

```
function parseContents($divID)
    {


    $page = file_get_contents('content/resources.html');
    $doc = new DOMDocument();

    @$doc->loadHTML($page);
    $divs = $doc->getElementsByTagName('div');

    foreach($divs as $div) 
        {
        if ($div->getAttribute('id') === $divID) 
            {
            echo $div->nodeValue;
            }
        }


    }

parseContents('listOfStuff');
```

Thanks for your help in understanding this a little better, let me know if I need to explain it any better :)

Answer (score 1):

See [Making AJAX Applications Crawlable](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/) published by Google.

Comment: going to look at this now, thanks for the suggestion. That's a search term i had not thought of. Thank you :)

Comment: +1 to this answer, but it will mean that you have to provide that information in a 'static' form. Its greay if you're considering a new site but maintaining the snapshots or automating them in an existing development will mean some work.

Comment: Thanks guys. I haven't figured it out yet, going to take a coffee break and re-read the Google page, but i think i can use that PHP code i came up with to create a dynamic screenshot if a manipulate it correctly. Presently, that PHP utilizes the exact same content but strips the markup, which should be fine for Google... A little out of my league, but it's how we learn :) thanks again!